# Fabric Crashlytics with Phonegap Build

Tags: android, cordova, crashlytics, twitter-fabric, crashlytics-android

I have signed up for Fabric.io and want to use Crashlytics with my Phonegap Build project.

I found the follow plugin:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-fabric-plugin

I feel as if all I should need is an API key and some other information from Fabric and do some configuration on my app. On the Fabric site to get anywhere I have to do this on-boarding process which involves having a xCode or Android Studio project which I don't have.

Is there anyway for this to work with a Phonegap Build project?

Comment: It should. Ask your question with the `phonegap-build` tag, and ask at the [official *Phonegap Build* forum](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi).

Comment: It's not possible, fabric requires the install of the SDK using their fabric app and that can't be done from phonegap build

Answer (score 2):

Nop it doesn't need API key

because in step 2 in the instructions of your link say :

"2 - (Important) Add Fabric SDK to the Android / iOS project Fabric.io"

so you need to prepare your codes in JS like in the readme

then integrate the native SDKs ( Android & IOS )

https://get.fabric.io/ios?locale=en-us

https://get.fabric.io/android?locale=en-us

then build and run

the native integrations already embedding api keys